# Derivative on parametrized manifold

Tags: functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus, manifolds

Let $U\subset \mathbb{R}^m$ is open and $\alpha: U\mapsto\mathbb{R}^n$ is $m-$dimensional parametrized manifold with $m\leq n$.

I have two following questions:

1. If we are given $v\in \alpha(U)$, can we find the corresponding $u\in U$ explicitly such that $\alpha(u)=v$.
2. I know that the tangent space at $u\in U$ is the subspace spanned by the Jacobian matrix of $\alpha$, isn't it? But, how will we find the tangent space at $\alpha(u)$.

I am sorry if it is very fundamental question. But, I am really confused about this concept. Any help and suggestion will be appreciated. I also will be very happy if somebody give me an appropriate reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) what do you mean by explicitly? A coordinate map is a bijection on it's image, so if $v\in \alpha(U)$ there exists exactly one $u\in U$ such that $\alpha(u)= v$. But in general there is not way to say more.

2) The tangent space of $\mathbb{R}^m$ at a point $u$ in $\mathbb{R}^m$ is just $\mathbb{R}^m$. The tangent space of the manifold $\alpha(U)$ in $v = \alpha(u)$ is (can be identified with, to be more precise)
$d\alpha(u)(\mathbb{R}^m)$, the image of the tangent space of the source under the differential of the coordinate map.

As a reference, any book on the theory of manifolds, Differential Geometry or Differential Topology should do. Try, e.g, Spivak's Calculus on manifolds.

Comment: Thanks @Thomas for your helps